# What happens to other processes when a Docker container's PID1 exits?

Tags: linux, docker, cgroups

Consider the following, which runs `sleep 60` in the background and then exits:

```
$ cat run.sh 
sleep 60&
ps
echo Goodbye!!!
$ docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/run.sh:/run.sh ubuntu:16.04 bash /run.sh
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 bash
    5 ?        00:00:00 sleep
    6 ?        00:00:00 ps
Goodbye!!!
```

This will start a Docker container, with `bash` as PID1. It then fork/execs a `sleep` process, and then `bash` exits. When the Docker container dies, the `sleep` process somehow dies too.

My question is: what is the mechanism by which the `sleep` process is killed? I tried trapping `SIGTERM` in a child process, and that appears to not get tripped. My presumption is that something (either Docker or the Linux kernel) is sending `SIGKILL` when shutting down the cgroup the container is using, but I've found no documentation anywhere clarifying this.

**EDIT** The closest I've come to an explanation is the following quote from [baseimage-docker](http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/):

> If your init process is your app, then it'll probably only shut down itself, not all the other processes in the container. The kernel will then forcefully kill those other processes, not giving them a chance to gracefully shut down, potentially resulting in file corruption, stale temporary files, etc. You really want to shut down all your processes gracefully.

So at least according to this, the implication is that when the container exits, the kernel will sending a SIGKILL to all remaining processes. But I'd still like clarity on how it decides to do that (i.e., is it a feature of cgroups?), and ideally a more authoritative source would be nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I seem to have come up with some more solid evidence that this is, in fact, the Linux kernel doing the terminating. In the `clone(2)` man page, there's this useful section:

> **CLONE_NEWPID** (since Linux 2.6.24)
>
> The first process created in a new namespace (i.e., the process
>   created using the CLONE_NEWPID flag) has the PID 1, and  is  the 
>   "init" process  for  the  namespace.   Children  that are orphaned
>   within the namespace will be reparented to this process rather than
>   init(8). Unlike the traditional init process, the "init" process of a
>   PID namespace can terminate, and if it does, all of the  processes  in
>   the  namespace are terminated.

Unfortunately this is still vague on how exactly the processes in the namespace are terminated, but perhaps that's because, unlike a normal process exit, no entry is left in the process table. Whatever the case is, it seems clear that:

- The kernel itself is killing the other processes
- They are not killed in a way that allows them any chance to do cleanup, making it (almost?) identical to a SIGKILL

Comment: It is possible for dockers `runc` to do the clean up if you are [running in the hosts pid namespace](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/c4e0d94efacd6f6fb353a538cc01d10792cc3a35/libcontainer/state_linux.go#L41-L45).

Comment: and the kernel does send a `SIGKILL` to terminate the processes.

Comment: @Matt Good to know. Does it become the host `init` process's responsibility to reap those, or does the kernel remove them from the process table itself as well?

Comment: When there's no NEWPID option on the docker container process  (`docker run --pid host`), the kernel has no facility to remove/kill the processes itself.  If Docker didn't manage to clean them up with that code, the processes would inherit the systems PID 1 as a parent process and possibly become a zombie.